Netsuite API transactionsearchbasic is not returning what I expect
When I specify multiple values it doesn't filter the results.  I am trying to get all invoices with a status of "open" and still have an amount remaining.
            Dim tsb As New wsNetSuite.TransactionSearchBasic

            Dim tranTypes As String() = New String() {"_invoice"}
            Dim semsfTranType As New wsNetSuite.SearchEnumMultiSelectField()
            semsfTranType.operatorSpecified = True
            semsfTranType.operator = wsNetSuite.SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf
            semsfTranType.searchValue = tranTypes
            tsb.type = semsfTranType

            Dim tranStatus As String() = New String() {"_invoiceOpen"}
            Dim semsfTranStatus As New wsNetSuite.SearchEnumMultiSelectField()
            semsfTranStatus.operatorSpecified = True
            semsfTranStatus.operator = wsNetSuite.SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf
            semsfTranStatus.searchValue = tranStatus
            tsb.status = semsfTranStatus

            Dim amtRem As New wsNetSuite.SearchDoubleField
            amtRem.operator = SearchDoubleFieldOperator.notEqualTo
            amtRem.operatorSpecified = True
            amtRem.searchValue = 0
            amtRem.searchValueSpecified = True
            tsb.amountRemaining = amtRem

            Dim ts As New wsNetSuite.TransactionSearch
            ts.basic = tsb

